# How can users view only their own posts in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I only show one post at random from the post.

But I want to show only the posts I made, not the whole posts.
(using Devise.)

Should I use cancancan and rolify gem?

I wonder how to do it without using it.

**posts controller**

```
  def index
    @posts = Post.order("RANDOM()").first(1)
  end
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<% @posts.each do |x| %>
    <div class="xxx">
    <div class="boxcolor">
      <div class="boxcolor2" style="background-color:<%=x.color%>;"></div>
    </div>    
    <div class="boxtit"><%=x.title%></div> 
    <div class="boxcon"><%=x.content%></div> 
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: If you're application supports login, then you can build association between `users` and `posts` and you can use `current_user.posts`, which would only list all the posts of the logged in user. If you let's say want to see a post of a specific `user`, then you can build a route like `/users/:id/posts` and pass in the `id` and get all the posts for that user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this into the controller otherwise, it shows an error while don't found the current user ID

```
before_action :authenticate_user!
```

and into index action use like this

```
@posts = current_user.posts.order("RANDOM()").first(1)
```

Comment: I get an error that I can not find .posts.

I want to access it from a controller other than the Post controller.

To do that, you have to use the Post model. Why can not I use the Post model in the code below?

ex) @posts = current_user.Post.order ("RANDOM ()"). first (1) //// not working

Comment: Because you don't have a method `Post` defined on user instance.

Comment: Can you elaborate what is the error with this solution?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you'll have to do it.

**routes.rb**

```
devise_for :users

resources :posts, only: :index
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end
```

**post.rb**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**posts_controller.rb**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def index
    @posts = current_user.posts.order("RANDOM()").first(1)
  end

end
```